# Bar Tint on UIToolBar when translucent is false

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitoolbar

I try to set the Bar Tint Color (in Interface Builder) on a `UIToolbar` that has `translucent` set to off. No matter the color I choose, the toolbar is always white in the emulator (it changes color in IB). I need to set translucent to true in order to have my `UIToolbar` with the right Bar Tint. From the Apple doc, I don't see anywhere mentioned that `barTintColor` is not working when `translucent` is set to false.

Thanks

**Edit**

It looks like this is an issue only in interface builder, setting Bar Tint Color in code is working, anyone can confirm?

Comment: Can you upload some screenshots? It's hard to tell with that info, cause it works for me.

Comment: As a workaround, you can set the background colour of the toolbar (a few settings below Bar Tint in the interface builder) to be what you want.

Comment: Did you set it in interface builder? Myles, I also discovered the background color trick, but I still try to understand why it's not working with bartintcolor

Answer (score 0):

from the docs

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIToolbar/translucent

> If you set this property to NO on a toolbar with a translucent custom background image, the toolbar provides an opaque background for the image using black if the toolbar has UIBarStyleBlack style, white if the toolbar has UIBarStyleDefault, or the toolbar’s barTintColor if a custom value is defined.

Comment: Yes I saw this part in the doc. What am I missing?

Comment: It says in second last line " white if the toolbar has UIBarStyleDefault " maybe ?

Comment: "or the toolbar’s barTintColor if a custom value is defined." which I defined a custom value.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will help you or not but if I open barTintColor in xcode documentation `@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *barTintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;  // default is nil` Hope this helps